# How to search mutiple text

Tags: excel-formula, valueerror

How do I search multiple text by using search formula?

I have tried multiple nested IF's but I am going over 64 levels but to overcome this problem, using multiple search would cut down some levels.

```
=search({"auburn", "hogansville", "lawrenceville"}, BR2)
```

Flowing formula gives value error why is that? I have googled and many people are using the exact same format above but for some reason its giving me a value error.

Comment: Does the cell BR2 contains a long text or only one of the words you're looking for?

Comment: BR2 contains long text for example, Auburn,AL but the search function neglects the capital and just finds the text so it should work but I dont understand

Comment: @JakePark  What is happening here is that you're getting an array returned from search but you're only looking at the first element.  Unless you match the first word (auburn) you'll see the a value error.  Follow the guidelines for arrays (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_2019) to visualise more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are checking for existence of any of those words, so you can use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"auburn", "hogansville", "lawrenceville"}, BR2)))>0
```

Which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: wow this worked could you explain what the -- does? and why sumproduct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(BR2,{"*auburn*", "*hogansville*", "*lawrenceville*"}))
```

Comment: This worked as well! could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: It does three COUNTIFS and sums the results.  The `*` are wildcards so as long as the word appears anywhere in the cell it will be counted.